# Office 365 Outlook Autodiscover using a reverse proxy - bad approach?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-office-365, autodiscovery

**Background.** Outlook Autodiscover has a certain order of trying to figure out configuration, and it's somewhat unchangeable, at least for Office 365 users with BYOD devices:

1. Domain apex `https://example.com:443/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml`. As this is typically a public web site hosted elsewhere, this seems like an unnecessary step for most.
2. `https://autodiscover.example.com:443/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml` is a way more reasonable alternative. Unfortunately, as of Sep 2019, Microsoft has screwed this up: for Office 365 users this is instructed to be a `CNAME autodiscover.outlook.com.`, but...

   ```
   $ curl -vvv https://autodiscover.outlook.com:443/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml
   *   Trying 40.101.49.88...
   * TCP_NODELAY set
   * connect to 40.101.49.88 port 443 failed: Connection refused
   *   Trying 40.101.65.216...
   * TCP_NODELAY set
   * connect to 40.101.65.216 port 443 failed: Connection refused
   *   Trying 40.101.126.120...
   * TCP_NODELAY set
   * connect to 40.101.126.120 port 443 failed: Connection refused
   *   Trying 40.101.126.216...
   * TCP_NODELAY set
   * connect to 40.101.126.216 port 443 failed: Connection refused
   *   Trying 2603:1026:207:15::8...
   * TCP_NODELAY set
   * connect to 2603:1026:207:15::8 port 443 failed: Connection refused
   *   Trying 2603:1026:207:109::8...
   . . .
   ```
3. Fallback to HTTP redirect method, the only method working.

   This time `http://autodiscover.example.com:80/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml`, configured as a `CNAME autodiscover.outlook.com.`, answers with a redirect to a working site.

   ```
   Location: https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml
   ```

   This one is serving correctly in most cases, although lines seems to be long for new Application Passwords to make it this far. This, how ever, takes a lot of request and additional time. (Also, this makes it harder to debug why certain versions of Outlook can't currently connect to Office 365 at all, but must be ugraded before even trying...)

**Possible solution** to make this faster is to add a reverse proxy at the domain apex, pointing to the working Office 365 Autodiscover site. E.g. with Apache this is as easy as enabling the module with `a2enmod proxy_http` and adding a simple configuration to the `VirtualHost`:

```
# Office 365 Autodiscover Hack 20190918
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPass "/Autodiscover/"  "https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/Autodiscover/"
ProxyPassReverse "/Autodiscover/"  "https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/Autodiscover/"
```

According to the [Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/) test for Outlook Autodiscover this seems to work perfectly fine, and it also seems to make Outlook Autodiscovery seemingly faster on actual Outlook installations.

As this is a hack rather than an actual solution documented anywhere, **my question: is there any possible consequences from this approach** you could think of?

Is the `autodiscover-s.outlook.com` for example a static hostname for the service, or does it ever give other redirects? Wouldn't Outlook just continue with steps 2 & 3 in any case this proxy gives unexpected results?

Comment: Related question: [Can HSTS includeSubDomains break Office 365 autodiscoveries?](https://serverfault.com/q/958307/274176)

Comment: Hey Esa, have you ever experienced any (negative) consequences from the redirect in the meanwhile? It has been almost 2 years. Perhaps you can answer your own question and/or add a comment. :) I just took a similar turn, [with a redirect at DNS provider](https://serverfault.com/a/1074992/), but if there are any downsides, I would like to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, adding a reverse proxy works without problems and prevents from trying unencrypted connections to `http://autodiscover.example.com:80/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml`. However, as [A71 noticed](https://serverfault.com/a/1074992/274176), Outlook also follows HTTP redirects from the HTTPS URIs on phases #1 & #2, omitting the plain HTTP phase #3.

A redirect might even be better from security perspective, as Office 365's Autodiscovery requires authentication. With a reverse proxy this authentication would be unnecessarily passed through the web server.

Also, as the URI from the domain apex web server is always requested first, a compromised *content management system* (CMS) could hijack these and steal user passwords. Therefore, having this configured on the web server level prevents any web application from getting these requests.

**As a result, the Office 365 Autodiscover gets both faster and more secure.**

Apache:

```
# Office 365 Autodiscover Redirect
Redirect permanent "/Autodiscover/" "https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/Autodiscover/"
```

Nginx:

```
# Office 365 Autodiscover Redirect
location /Autodiscover/ {
    return 301 https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @A71, for this better alternative. Here's my reasoning on why this is better & why it could even be considered as a best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Office 365 and Exchange Online environment has a different character from the Exchange on-Premises environment. In Exchange on-Premises environment, the organization uses a dedicated Public facing Exchange server, which serves as a “representative” for the organization public domain name.
The “cloud environment” (Office 365), cannot provide this type of “dedicated Exchange server” that will represent the particular domain name of the Office 365 tenant. Please refer to this article:
https://o365info.com/autodiscover-flow-in-an-office-365-environment-part-1-of-3-part-29-of-36/

Comment: This partly answers the question on why the phase 2 is supposed to fail, but the other parts are just repeating what has already been established in the question. It doesn't answer if there's any reason not to take the shortcut with a reverse proxy. As it has a matching certificate, it's working.